# Invalid Literal Stockfish python 3.10

Tags: python, stockfish

I am trying to use the stockfish package in python on Linux, and I'm running into a rather odd error. I downloaded the zip file from the official repo:

https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish

And I've unzipped it and used the makefile to compile it. However, when I try to initialize stockfish in any bit of actual code:

```
stockfish = Stockfish(path = "/username/Chess/Engines/Stockfish-master/src/stockfish")
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/username/.conda/envs/alpha/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stockfish/models.py", line 57, in __init__ 
self._stockfish_major_version: int = int(
ValueError: invalid literal for int with base 10: 'dev202211114nogit'
```

I've tried a couple of the unofficial binaries for linux as well (found here: https://stockfishchess.org/download/linux/), and they've also given me the same error, albeit with a slightly different string in the final line.

I'm really unsure as to what's going on, since I've tested my installation method on a different (much weaker, hence my desire to fix this issue) computer, and it worked fine with all the same setup. I'm using python 3.10, with stockfish 3.28.0. If anyone has experience with this particular issue, or if they have any advice as to how to begin solving it, I would sincerely appreciate it. If there are any details that I've omitted that might be of use, please let me know and I'll edit them in. Cheers.

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/zhelyabuzhsky/stockfish/blob/master/stockfish/models.py#L58), it looks like the string it's trying to parse comes from `Stockfish._read_line`, which reads from the Stockfish process' STDOUT (standard output.) The code that's parsing the process' STDOUT expects the string to look a certain way, but it obviously doesn't look that way. Either there's a bug in Stockfish, the Python wrapper, or something on your system is injecting stuff to that process' STDOUT.

Comment: Scratch that. Looking at your code again, I think this is probably due to the fact that the path you're passing in to `Stockfish(path="...")` is incorrect. This should be a path to the executable stockfish program, not a directory. I'm not familiar with Linux, but on Windows, for example, the path would be something like `path="C:/path/to/program/stockfish.exe"`

Comment: I know the path looks weird, but I'm fairly certain it's correct. I've looked at the file, and it simply does not have an extension (or, if it does, it's not something that my OS is picking up on). In any case, on my weaker test bench, the following path:

stockfish = Stockfish(path = "/username/Desktop/stockfish_15_linux_x64_avx2/stockfish_15_x64_avx2")

works fine, so I'm hesitant to say it's that.

Comment: Looking at the C++ side this time, `Stockfish-master/src/misc.cpp` . Read the comments on lines 140 - 148. It looks like you've built a debug dev build. You have to build a release non-dev build to get the correct STDOUT output that includes the version number.

Comment: Wow, that's a good catch. Thank you for that. Forgive me if this is a rather trivial question, but how does one go about doing that? The command I used the last time was:

make build ARCH=x86-64 (it's a 64 bit Linux OS)

Thanks again for this!

Comment: No worries - can't help you there unfortunately, since I'm a Windows guy who builds all his stuff through IDEs and GUIs haha.

Comment: Though it'll probably be something simple like adding a missing `--release` build flag or something like that. I would look at the documentation of your build tools for specifics.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't looking closely. Seems like you don't have to fiddle with compiler flags. You just have to set the variable `const string version = "dev"` on line 71 of `misc.cpp` to something that isn't `"dev"`.

Comment: Hm, I gave that a try, but still the same error. I'm going to look at the file referenced in the error to see if I have any more luck.

Comment: You could run the stockfish executable from the terminal to see what it prints out, then modify the source of the stockfish package accordingly.

Comment: I followed the advice by Paul M and changed `const string version = "dev"` to `const string version = "16"` and it worked. When I now call `stockfish.get_stockfish_major_version()` I get "16": is that because I'm actually using version 16 or is it just spitting out the const string value?